# Error When upgrading umbraco 4.9.1 to 4.10.0

Tags: content-management-system, version, umbraco, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade umbraco project in version 4.9.1 to 4.10.0 using nuget package but i am getting this kind of error.
[Please check here as attached in screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3RR8.png)
Please help guys, Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Are you also trying to upgrade Contour? The bit of code it's looking for didn't exist until way after 1.1.13.

Comment: When i upgraded umbraco project in version 4.9.1 to 4.10.0, Contour package was not being installed, I mean I have had Umbraco contour package installed in the version 4.9.1 but that package was not being installed in the version 4.10.0 while upgrading, That's why i was trying to install the contour package in version 4.10.0 and when i try to install contour package, I am having the same error i attached in screenshot, Thanks Tim :)